# Access error uploading file using winsp

Tags: permissions, ftp

I am trying to upload two files to a webserver so my teacher can see it. I am using winsp since my filezila doesnt work. But for some reason it is telling me that i don't have access to that page. Can anyone tell me why is it doing that.Here is a picture of my screen. 
[image: what my winsp looks like]

I am just not understanding why it is telling me that i don't have to access it.

Comment: i dont think the code has anything todo with your access rights. ask your teacher...

Comment: You can press the `Print Screen` key.

Comment: @SLaks Boo. That's how I'm going to do all my screenshots from now on.

Comment: make sure you're going __into__ the public_html directory.  I don't know what your school's permission rights are, but it doesn't have anything to do with the code.

Comment: Maybe it needs to be put in public_html? very rough guess of course, we'd need to understand the configuration of the web server to really help you.

Comment: ok thank you everyone!!! i am still working on it. It is also in the public yeah i am thinking it has something with what my teacher wants done but he has not responded back to me yet.Thank you all for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem definitly isn't in code. There is error while uploading files. Can you connect to FTP regulary? If you can. Look for Active or Passive file transfer to FTP. Also if you can upload files, files must be in public_html folder to be visible from browser.

[Active or passive](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html)

Answer (score 2):

If I had to take a guess, that public_html folder is your public directory where you should put things that anybody can get to (like through a browser).  You have your files outside of that directory, so your page can't access them.

edit:

It's an *educated* guess, as I have seen a fair amount of server configurations that name the public web folder as such (other common names are "www" and "httpdocs")

Answer (score 0):

First read Neal comment. 
second, you should probably copy the files into the /public_html folder, instead of the / (root) folder.